# How to deselect a selection in word using the office js API

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I've build an app relying on the user to make certain selections and the app then react accordingly.

However i want to deselect the selected text after the app has done the work.

I can not see anywhere in the API an option to allow me to deselect the current selection.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [select()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) method and pass in either `'start'` or `'end'` as the parameter. This will result in deselecting the text and placing the cursor at either the start or end of the object.

Do deselect the current selection you can use the following:

```
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        range.select('start');
        return context.sync();
    })
```

*Note that you can execute this against a [range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range), [paragraph](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph) or entire [body](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body) so `body.select('start')` will place the cursor at the beginning of the document while `paragraph.select('start')` will place it at the beginning of the current paragraph.*

Comment: Oh man thanks A LOT! I was googling for "deselect" and found nothing!